# Next JS: Get URL fragment with context (on getServerSideProps)

Tags: typescript, next.js, server-side-rendering

I want to get a URL fragment on getServerSideProps. The URL as the following structure: `http://localhost:3000/some-folder#desiredParam=value`

I am passing the `context` as a parameter to the `getServerSideProps` function, but I haven't been able to retrieve the URL param because the structure of the URL isn't `http://localhost:3000/some-folder?desiredParam=value`. If it was like this, I could just use `context.query.desiredParam`

Using `context.query.url` returns `/some-folder` and `context.query` returns null.

If I could just retrieve the whole `window.location` I would split the string by `#`, but that's not possible on getServerSideProps.

So... what can I do to get the desiredParam's value?

Comment: This is for an oAuth integration and the implicit authorization provider passes the authorization URL with a fragment instead of a URL param, which I understand is safer because it can't be intercepted by browsers. 

A solution would be to simply call the function I built on getServerSideProps on the frontend, but for performance, it would be nicer if I could somehow get the value with the context API.

Answer (score 1):

The URL fragment is an inherently client-side concept.

It is not sent with the HTTP GET-request. You can change it without triggering any request at all. This is not due to your framework, it is basic web standards.
Client-side frameworks just don't run into this, since they are, well, client-side.

If you want server-side content to depend on the fragment you need to extract it client-side and pass the data to the server in some other way.